# Is there a safe way to run my own macro?

Tags: microsoft-word, security, macros

As of winter, 2016, is there some safe way of running my own macros in MS Word?  I want to create a simple macro, make a button for it, and then be able to run the macro in any Word document I might create.

When I try to run the macro, I get a complaint about the macro security settings.

I use Word 2010.  I doubt this is relevant, but just in case, I was apparently using a trial version which expired after a fairly long period.  All features seem to be working fine, but every time I restart Word, I have to "cancel" the attempt Word makes to ask me for a different key.

Comment: You can configure Word to only allow macros in a whitelist.

Comment: You should first buy a legitimate copy of Word.

Comment: " If you don't convert to the Full product by the end of the Trial version's time limit, the software runs in Reduced Functionality mode.

In Reduced Functionality mode, your software behaves similarly to a viewer. You cannot save modifications to documents or create any new documents, and additional functionality might be reduced. No existing files or documents are harmed in Reduced Functionality mode. Full functionality returns when you activate or convert the software."

Comment: @DavidPostill - Well, I just haven't taken the time yet to transfer Office from the mostly defunct laptop to the one I'm using now.  Thanks for your explanation.  If you write it as an answer I would like to accept it.

Comment: @aparente001 Answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

#### When I start Word, I have to "cancel" it asking for a different key.

This is because your trial has expired. You need to install a legitimate copy of Word.

An expired trial version has restrictions:

> If you don't convert to the Full product by the end of the Trial version's time limit, the software runs in Reduced Functionality mode.
>
> In Reduced Functionality mode, your software behaves similarly to a viewer. You cannot save modifications to documents or create any new documents, and additional functionality might be reduced. No existing files or documents are harmed in Reduced Functionality mode. Full functionality returns when you activate or convert the software.

Source [Office 2010 Trial – Expired](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_other/office-2010-trial-expired/23f8903e-5b08-4b4b-94af-31af5f94eec8)

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I just realized I'm a bit confused. I actually can create new documents without any trouble. But I guess the take-home message is that my problems running macros may be related to the reduced functionality (which I suppose might be variable or unpredictable).  So it's just a coincidence that MS increased security protections related to running macros?  I should try creating and running a macro on my desktop computer, where Office is happy with the key.  (Oddly, Office was running happily on this laptop for a long time before the problem with the key appeared.)

Comment: I will try and find some more information about the reduced functionality.

Comment: @aparente001 You can try [Rearm' trick extends Office 2010 free ride to 180 days](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2516549/desktop-apps/-rearm--trick-extends-office-2010-free-ride-to-180-days.html) and see if your macros now work. That will give you some time to move your legitimate install.

Comment: Probably not right away, but I will see what happens on my desktop.  I have a vague idea I was having some trouble with the macro security settings there last time I tried to save a macro there too.  Plus a came across an article that said that hackers have been using macros to infect computers and therefore Microsoft tightened up macro security greatly, I think the article was from last summer.